# How to compile multiple JavaScript files in Laravel Mix using different compilation settings for each file

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have an application that provides a downloadable JavaScript integration script for the application API. I would like to be able to compile this integration file using different settings compared to the main application front-end.

webpack.mix.js

```
// Compile js integration
mix.js('resources/js/integrations/FilterIntegration', 'integrations/filter.js');

// Compile the main application
mix.js('resources/js/layout/Root.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .extract(['react', 'react-router-dom', 'lodash']);
```

My problem is that this setup actually applies all the following chained commands to each of the compiled files. This means that my compiled integration file also has to use the **vendor.js** and **manifest.js** files that are created for the main application by the **extract** command and it also includes a **sass import statement** although obviously the integration has nothing to do with styles as it's simply ment as a JavaScript library.

**So my question is the following**: How do I set up my Laravel Mix compilation in a way where I can conveniently compile the integration libraries with settings separate from the main application?